# I cant insert data to db using ajax in laravel 5.2

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel-5

I wonder if its because of the model, and I dont know where to put model file and what to write on it, im new to laravel 5.2

html (testing.blade.php)

```
<input type="text"id="name" name="name">
<button type="submit" id="add">ADD</button>
```

ajax

```
    $("#add").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'addItem',
            data: {
                '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
                'name': $('input[name=name]').val()
            },
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            },
        });
        $('#name').val('');
    });
```

routes

```
Route::post ('test', 'CommentsController@addItem' );
```

controller

```
public function addItem(Request $request) {
    $data = new Comments ();
    $data->comment = $request->name;
    $data->save ();
    return response ()->json ( $data );
}
```

Comment: in ajax call url should be route name, in your case 'test' instead of 'addItem'

Comment: moreover there is no input element as '_token' in your blade file

Comment: I already change the ajax call still dont insert

Comment: input element _token is necessary

Comment: sorry but how would I do that?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf this link might help you

Comment: There is a space missing in your input tag: `type="text__"id="name"`.

Answer (score 1):

- You need to add the csrf field and send this value to the server.
- The ajax url need to match with the route element (not with the controller function name)

**BLADE:**

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
<input type="text" id="commentName" name="commentName">
<button type="submit" id="add">ADD</button>
```

**AJAX:**

```
$("#add").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/add-item',
    data: {
      '_token': $('input[name="_token"]').val(),
      'name': $('input[name="commentName"]').val()
    },
    success: function(data) {
      alert(data);
    },
  });
  $('#name').val('');
});
```

**ROUTE:**

```
Route::post ('add-item', 'CommentsController@addItem');
```

[Documentation regarding to CSRF Protection.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf)